# How to find the minimum number of elements to distinguish several given sets?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, terminology, reference-request, sets

Given $n$ distinct sets $S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_n$, how to find a set $X$ such that $X \cap S_1, X \cap S_2, \cdots, X \cap S_n$ are still distinct, and the size of $X$ is minimum?

For example, given $\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}$, let $X=\{1, 2\}$, then the intersections are $\{1, 2\}, \{1\}, \{2\}$, which are still different from each other.

Are there any efficient algorithms better than enumerating all possible sets? Is there an official name for this problem?

Comment: Any limits/constraints on the number of sets or the range of set elements?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur No constraints. I don't think there could be an efficient deterministic and efficient solution. I just wonder whether there could be an approximation algorithm.

Comment: That is an awesome question! Thank you for asking. I am not aware of a name for this problem, or of an obvious reduction to another problem.

Comment: Very similar to [set cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)

Comment: Can an intersection be empty?

Comment: If $\Delta_{ij} = (S_i \setminus S_j) \cup (S_j \setminus S_i)$, then you want to guarantee that $X \cap \Delta_{ij} \ne \emptyset$ for all $i$ and $j$. Now it becomes a hitting problem, which is equivalent to the set cover problem, which is NP-hard. The sets are not arbitrary though, so a faster solution might exists.

Comment: This problem, "Minimal Key Set" is NP-hard. The hitting set problem can be reduced to this problem, as shown [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220816215759/https://win-vector.com/2019/06/16/minimal-key-set-is-np-hard/).